# Magento 1.7 minimum qty allowed and configurable products

Tags: magento-1.7, configurable-product

I'm sort of at a loss on this one. I changed the 'Minimum Qty Allowed' setting in the admin and now I don't see the add 2 cart button for any products. I think it's just configurable products that this affected.

EDIT: I deleted the minimum qty allowed rule and it's still showing no 'add to cart' button.
Also, manage stock is set to 'No'

I can't seem to figure out why this is or what to do about it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Even though I'm sure I already did this, it seems like re-indexing worked.

Answer (score 1):

Just a blind guess: maybe quantity of those products is below that new value of 'Minimum Qty Allowed' which you have just set?

Comment: The only thing is now that I set it back, it's still showing no 'add to cart' button